# string to list of dictionaries (python)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, split

I have a string that needs to be split 3 ways and then into a list of dictionaries.

```
given_string = 'name:mickey,age:58|name:minnie,age:47,weight:60' 

data = []

data = [value.split(',') for value in given_string.split('|')]

data = [['name:mickey', 'age:58'], ['name:minnie', 'age:47', 'weight:60']]
```

Now I want to split this one more time on the ':' and have the data contain a list of two dictionaries so that when I input say data[1][age], I get 47.

Basically, I think I want this for it to work:

```
data = [{'name': 'mickey', 'age': '58}, {'name': 'minnie', 'age': '47', 'weight': '60'}]
```

I believe that ultimately, data should be a list of dictionaries but once I split the string into two lists, I get confused in splitting it on the ':' and then converting the sublists to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest harder.

```
>>> [ dict(y.split(':') for y in x.split(',')) for x in 'name:mickey,age:58|name:minnie,age:47,weight:60'.split('|')]
[{'age': '58', 'name': 'mickey'}, {'age': '47', 'name': 'minnie', 'weight': '60'}]
```

Comment: I attempted this but I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @user1589244: one thing which would cause that is if you accidentally rebound the builtin name `dict` to a list, i.e. did something like `dict = [whatever]` at some point.

Comment: i tried this again but with dict = {} first. Then I got this error instead: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @user1589244 you need to `del dict` to restore the right value

Comment: @JBernardo this worked. What does the del dict do exactly? Does this mean dict had stored values before?

Comment: @user1589244: It removes the shadowing of the built-in `dict`.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio! So if I don't 'del dict' the answers above won't work. Is there an alternate solution then? I've always learned (so far) to set dict = {} if it's a dictionary ahead of time but this gets an error. Sorry it's a basic question but I'm a long way away from being proficient in python.

Comment: @user1589244: Stop using names used by built-in types.

Answer (score 4):

You can do with a simple list comprehension

```
>>> [dict(x.split(':') for x in parts.split(',')) 
     for parts in given_string.split('|')]
[{'age': '58', 'name': 'mickey'}, {'age': '47', 'name': 'minnie', 'weight': '60'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 given_string = 'name:mickey,age:58|name:minnie,age:47,weight:60' 
 data = [value.split(',') for value in given_string.split('|')]

 y=[] # make a empty list
 for i in data:
     z={}
     for v in range(len(i)):
         b=i[v].split(":")      #  ['name", "mickey', 'age","58"]
         z[b[0]]=b[1]           # adding keys and values in dictionary z  
     y.append(z)                # adding dictionary to the list
```