# How can I import a str with a list of dicts into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

How can I transform this string containing data from json into a dataframe?

```
s = "[{u'website': u'', u'volume': u'0', u'price': u'0.00000510', u'id': u'', u'name': u''}, {u'website': u'', u'volume': u'0.00032510', u'price': u'0.0000000000000000', u'id': u' abcd', u'name': u' ABCD'}, {u'website': u'', u'volume': u'0', u'price': u'0.00000003', u'id': u' ktae', u'name': u' KTAE'}]"
```

I've fetched this info using a website API, converted the json response to str and stored it into a sql database.

Now I've fetched this string from my db and I want to create a dataframe with it.

**How can I do that?**

I've tried this code, but without success:

```
jdata = json.load(s)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata)
```

The code above produced a df with
`[384806 rows x 1 columns]`

Then I tried to use index... again without success:

```
columns = ['website', 'volume_btc', 'price_btc', 'id', 'name']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata, index=columns)
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 384806), indices imply (1, 5)
```

**How can I use a list comprehension to get this info from str to a dict format and import it into a pandas dataframe?**

Maybe something like this...

```
dict_data = [ dict(y.split(':') for y in x.split(',')) for x in data2.split('}, {')]
```

I've found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963726/string-to-list-of-dictionaries-python) but I don't know how can I use it effectively in my problem.. Any1 have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your string `s` isn't a regular JSON string.
But you can try [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate it as a python object, a list of dict, and let pandas handle it :

```
In [12]: s = eval(s)

In [13]: pd.DataFrame(s)
Out[13]: 
      id   name               price      volume website
0                        0.00000510           0        
1   abcd   ABCD  0.0000000000000000  0.00032510        
2   ktae   KTAE          0.00000003           0
```

Comment: Wow!! This worked!! You holy `eval()` command saved my work. Actually I'm using python 2.x, but it worked anyway. I'm gonna take a deep look at  `eval()` docs. Really thanks!!